# Connecting to local mongodb via nodejs is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript

So I'm having a lot of problems connecting to MongoDB on my local windows install. Eventually the MongoClient.Connect function executes my callback (maybe 20 seconds after I call it), and it just fails with a really unhelpful error: [image: mongo connect error]

I've included the relevant code below... hopefully it's minimal enough to get my point across.

```
config = require '../../config.json'
databaseEngine = config.storage #this is 'mongo'

Database = if databaseEngine is 'mongo' then require('mongodb').MongoClient else require 'nedb'

class ModuleDatabase

    load: () =>
        if not @label?.length then throw new Error "Database must have a name."
        if not @root?.length then throw new Error "Module must have a shortName of length 1 or greater."

        if databaseEngine is 'mongo'

            if not ModuleDatabase::databaseConnection
                Database.connect "mongodb://localhost:28017/kurea", {server:{auto_reconnect:true}}, (e, db) =>
                    console.log 'mongo!'
                    throw e if e?

                    ModuleDatabase::databaseConnection = db

                    @db = ModuleDatabase::databaseConnection.collection "#{@root}_#{@label}"
            else
                @db = ModuleDatabase::databaseConnection.collection "#{@root}_#{@label}"
```

Comment: What is the content of `err`? Log it to the console instead of just throwing it.

Comment: I feel super embarrassed, but it looks like I just had the wrong port the whole time. I don't know how it slipped my mind to try/catch that block of code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, port 28107 (or mongodbs port+1000) is the diagnostics port, and you can't actually use that to interface with the database. Who knew?

Comment: FYI, there is a list of [default ports](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/) in the MongoDB manual :)

Comment: Thanks for that bit of info! Yeah, being most familiar with MySQL/MariaDB, I knew they only operated on one database port and didn't have a diagnostics one. Because of this, I took the first one I saw in the command line.